# Probability with average of measures

Tags: probability

I am trying to solve `Problem 2` from [this](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~karikriz/TMA4240-H13/ov9-e.pdf) problem set.

> Let $\mathbf{Y}$ be the avreage of $5$ independent measurements.
>   For a single measurement one have $\sigma^2 = 0.060^2$ and $\mu = 6.8$.
>
> $\textbf{b})$ What is the probability that $\mathbf{Y}$ deviates more than $0.06$ from $\mu$ ?

I tried to use the probability that one measurement deviated more than $0.06$ from $\mu$. And then the total probability should be $1 - P(\text{all are below } 0.06)$.
But I see that this is wrong. 
I also tried calculating 
$$
    1 - P\left( Z < \frac{5\cdot 6.8- (5\cdot 6.8 + 0.06)}{\sigma/\sqrt{5}} \right)= 1 - P(Z<\sqrt{5\ \!})
$$
Which also turns out to be false. The correct answer should be 
P = $0.026$, but I can not quite get there. I am not experienced with dealing with 
the average of independent measurements, so any literature, hints or tips is very welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The questions says "results which are assumed to be independent and normally distributed", which is important to note.

In effect you are being asked to find the distribution of $Y$ (which is a mean, not a sum as in your expression).

- What is the expected value of $Y$? (It is *not* $5\cdot 6.8$.)
- What is the standard deviation of $Y$? (As you seem to say, it is $\sigma/\sqrt5$.)

Now, what is the probability of $Y$ deviates from $\mu$ by more than $0.06$?  Remember that $Y$ might be greater than or less than $\mu$, and the deviation here probably means the absolute value of the difference.

Comment: If you can mind continuing the discussion in chat? =)

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar: I don't use chat

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand what the expectancy value of Y is if it is not $5 \cdot 6.8$. Can you try to elaborate a bit more, or provide some relevant literature?

Comment: If the expected value of a single measurement is $\mu$, then the expected value of the **sum** of five measurements is $5  \mu$, but the expected value of the **average** of five measurements is $\dfrac{5  \mu}{5}=\mu$. In the same way, if the measurements are independent and the variance of one measurement is $\sigma^2$, then  then the variance  of the sum of five measurements is $5  \sigma^2$ and the standard deviation of the sum is $\sqrt{5} \sigma$, but the standard deviation of the average is $\dfrac{\sqrt{5} \sigma}{5}=\dfrac{\sigma}{\sqrt{5} }$

Comment: \begin{align*}
P(|Y-\mu|>0.06) & = 1-P(\mu-0.06 < Y < \mu + 0.06) \\  
                & = 1 - [P(X<\mu+0.06)-P(x < \mu-0.06)] \\
                & = 1 - \left[ P\left(Z < \frac{(\mu-0.06)-(\mu)}{\sigma/\sqrt{5}}\right) - P\left(Z < \frac{(\mu+0.06)-(\mu)}{\sigma/\sqrt{5}}\right)\right] \\
                & = 1 + P(z<-\sqrt{5}) - P(Z<\sqrt{5}) \\ 
                & \approx 0.1375
\end{align*}
I still get that the mu's cancel even after using the correct mu. Where is my fatal mistake?

Comment: @N3buchadnezzar: You should have $P(|Y-\mu| \gt 0.06) = P(Z \lt -\sqrt{5})+P(Z \gt +\sqrt{5}) = P(Z \lt -\sqrt{5})+1-P(Z \le +\sqrt{5}) $ $\approx 0.01267366 +0.01267366 = 0.02534732$ so I think your error is in your last line